# iOS Simulator recreates sql database/table

Tags: ios, sql, ios-simulator, xcode6.4

I'm using XCode 6.4 and iOS Si,mulator iPhone 6. Every run of my app database or table is recreated so i lost all previously inserted data. I have 1 database with 1 table inside. Database file is located in Supporing Files directory of the project. Here is the code for database initialization:

```
    BOOL success;
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"signals" ofType:@"sql"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"exists");
        return;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No file found");
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePath toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    }
```

On run - success variable is YES - so i see in logs "exists". After that i insert one item to my table and do select query that returns this one inserted raw. On next run i should see two rows, but there is only one row again - so i assume the table was recreated. I need help with this problem.

Comment: What is `[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePath toPath:databasePath error:nil];` supposed to do? You are simply missing out on copying the database file from your app bundle into the documents directory of your app (which survives app updates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not got enough reputations to comment, but if you're not getting any **No file found** messages in your log, then I don't think this is the block of code that is causing the problem.  Are you definitely doing an **Insert** query into the database and not an **Update**?  Also, is your **Select** query returning all rows and not just one.  Are you running through **XCode** or directly in the **Simulator**?  **XCode** might overwrite the files if you're running it just through there - try re-running the app in the Simulator (**CMD** + **Shift** + **H** to get to the home screen), and seeing if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank for answer! I just rerun app from simulator and all works ok. Seems XCode is guilty. If you know how to save database for each new XCode run - i will be happy! But you already helped me a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug in the simulator or in Xcode.  There is a bug in your app and not in the simulator itself.  You should not be modifying the database at this location:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"signals" ofType:@"sql"];
```

That is not persistent across updates of the application.  You will see the same issue when updating your app on device.

Instead, use a persistent location, like:

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documents = [directories firstObject];
```